# IntelliJ Play Scala incorrect warnings?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I just create a new Play Scala application (Play 2.6, IntelliJ 2017) and I keep getting this weird error. Sbt compiles and the app runs fine.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which specific version of IntelliJ are you using? I have been experiencing those with the latest EAP version.

Comment: IntelliJ Idea gives false errors since ever,

Comment: I use 2017.2.EAP but when I import the Play 2.5 starter project, everything is fine. It seems to be project related, but I compared the project and there where no differences.

Comment: Play 2.6 is not supported in IDEA yet. It is a work in progress and will be available in one of the next minor releases.